# Dividir uma string que contenha pontuações

Tags: php, string

Eu estou a tentar dividir a seguinte string

```
Eu irei amanhã à casa. E tu vens?
```

Para obter o seguinte resultado dentro de um array em php

```
array(
    [0] => eu
    [1] => irei
    [2] => amanhã
    [3] => à
    [4] => casa
    [5] => .
    [6] => E
    [7] => tu
    [8] => vens
    [9] => ?
)
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se fossem só espaços, seria caso de

```
$partes = explode( ' ', $todo );
```

Uma solução, dependendo do que quer, seria forçar um espaço antes dos caracteres que quer tratar como isolados:

```
$todo = str_replace( array( '.', ',' ,'?' ), array( ' .', ' ,', ' ?'), $todo );
$partes = explode( ' ', $todo );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/jVo72l)**.

Note que eu coloquei os separadores válidos diretamente no replace, mas se você quiser fazer isto com uma série de caracteres, compensa uma função mais complexa.

Se preferir considerar todos os alfanuméricos separados dos símbolos, pode usar uma *RegEx*, e resolver numa linha só:

```
preg_match_all('~\w+|[^\s\w]+~u', $todo, $partes );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/uClOcm)**.

Além disso, seria o caso de acrescentar espaços antes e depois dos símbolos, remover espaços duplos, depende do critério. A intenção da resposta foi só dar um rumo inicial.

Comment: Maravilha! Obrigado ;)

Comment: cool! (+1)... preg_match_all : o php é melhor do que eu  pensava!

Comment: @JJoao é só um wrapper, a implementação é a PCRE, o PHP só acessa a funcionalidade de lib de terceiros. Seria a mesma coisa em Harbour ou qualquer linguagem que acesse essa lib.

Answer (score 7):

Uma abordagem mais genérica seria usar `regex` para solucionar o problema.

```php
$string = "Eu irei amanhã à casa. E tu vens?";

/*
    Adiciona um espaço em todos os boundaries da string
    Ex.: Início e fim de palavras, pontuações, etc...
    O modificador 'u' e para tratar a string como Unicode
*/
$resultado = preg_replace('/\b/u', ' ', $string);

// Cria um array usando como delimitador um regex que casa com qualquer espaço
$resultado = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($resultado));

var_dump($resultado);
```

**output**:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "Eu"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "irei"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "amanhã"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "à"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "casa"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "."
  [6]=>
  string(1) "E"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "tu"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "vens"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "?"
}
```

Fiz [este código de exemplo](http://ideone.com/aldyKW) para ilustrar.

Comment: Bem prático. Muito bom! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Baseando-me 99.9% na resposta do @bacco... descaradamente!

```
preg_match_all('~\b\w[\w\-.*#]*\w\b|\w|\.\.\.|[,.:;()[\]?!]|\S~u', $t, $ps);
print_r($ps)

( [0] => Array
   (    [0] => Baseando-me
        [1] => 99.9
        [2] => %
        [3] => na
        [4] => resposta
        [5] => do
        [6] => @
        [7] => bacco
        [8] => ...
        [9] => descaradamente
        [10] => !
    )
)
```

**Upgrade** Na realidade tokenizar texto nos seus elementos é por vezes complexo: texto não são só palavras simples...

Segues-se uma abordagem um pouco mais robusta (empreguei `~ux` para
melhor legibilidade):

```
  preg_match_all('~
           https?://\S+             ## url
         | \d+/\d+/\d+              ## data
         | \b\w [\w\-.*#]* \w\b     ## vou-me 12.2 f.html
         | \w
         | \.\.\.                   ## ...
         | [!?]+                    ## ???   ?!
         | [,.:;()[\]]
         | \S
         ~ux', $todo, $partes );
     print_r($partes)
```

Perigo: (não testada...)

Comment: Eu gostei do complemento, seria legal mencionar as diferenças na resposta para o pessoal que não conhece RegEx acompanhar (por exemplo, mencionar que implementou a composição com ponto e traço, detecção das reticências etc).

Comment: @Bacco: acho que ainda lancei mais confusão...

Comment: Ficou bem melhor com a explicação, para entenderem as mudanças..